# JUnit 5 test case for code that write files to file system. (Files.write)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I am fairly new with Junit and I need to write JUnit 5 test case for a method which has code statement:

```
public void method() {
    // some code
    Files.write(filepath)
    // some more code
}
```

- Will this code create new files every time when unit test is run ?
- Is there a way to write a unit test for this scenario where files are not being created, or get deleted automatically once the test method execution is complete ?

Solution needs to be JUnit 5 compatible.

Comment: You can mock static methods with `PowerMock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used **JUnit 5's Temporary Directory(`@TempDir`)** functionality to create a temporary directory and then pass the directory path to `Files.write()` method (along with the file name of course). The `@TempDir` will delete the files and temporary folder, it created, once the test execution is done. This way, I was able to execute the test case.